# solr----RequestHandlerBaseorg.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field <field-name>

Tags: solr

we have setup solr master slave setup on 2 servers in GCP. using solr 8 version.
added a sample document to a core into master and then ran the search query and got the output.
in slave node the replication happened and status also shows the same index,count and all other details correctly but when i run a search query in slave it throws below error

ERROR true x:demo-solr
RequestHandlerBase

```
`org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field weight
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field weight
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1303)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getWrappedAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:441)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.DelegatingAnalyzerWrapper$DelegatingReuseStrategy.getReusableComponents          ``      `(DelegatingAnalyzerWrapper.java:86)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:192)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.QueryBuilder.createFieldQuery(QueryBuilder.java:239)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.newFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:518)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.newFieldQuery(QueryParser.java:62)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:1077)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:800)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:421)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:278)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:162)`
```

```
at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:131)
at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:254)
at org.apache.solr.searKch.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:49)
at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:173)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:158)
at           ``org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:272)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2559)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:711)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:516)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:3
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you also replicating the configuration files between the instances, or just the index?

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for responding 

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/index-replication.html#configuring-the-replication-requesthandler-on-a-slave-server

using this doc to implement this.

added below line in master node- solrconfig.xml file
<str name="confFiles">solrconfig_slave.xml:solrconfig.xml,x.xml,y.xml</str>

Comment: Verify that the schema has been replicated as you assume on the local disk on the slave - if the field is missing from the schema, Solr won't allow searching against it.

Comment: you are referrring to the managed-schema file from conf folder(master server). Isn't it??

if yes, then ya its replicated and i can see it on slave node

Comment: Yes, depending on how you've configured your instance. Just having the solrconfig replicated won't help, but you can check the active schema on your replication node by going to the admin interface and looking at the active schema there. The schema also have to be replicated to the replication node.

Comment: Hey, the schemas are not present in slave.
I mean i have a huge list in master but i am unable to see all of them in slave.
Can you please help me with what needs to be done to fix this please

Comment: Make sure they're added to the list of configuration files to replicate to the replicated node, and make sure that the node receives them when it attempts to replicate (for example on startup).